# Node.js mongodb and Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am quite new to node.js and Heroku and am struggling to figure out why my application won't work. Here is the code I think is relevant to my problem:

app.js:

```
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/myapp');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "express-validator": "^3.1.1",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.17",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.4",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node": "0.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "session": "^0.1.0",
    "stripe": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

Heroku Logs:

2017-01-03T12:04:38.470314+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fwc-node.herokuapp.com request_id=504519b3-45b1-4bf0-afcb-cd2376d6a10d fwd="2.102.204.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2017-01-03T12:06:02.536940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-01-03T12:06:06.929361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./bin/www`

2017-01-03T12:06:09.273120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-01-03T12:06:09.257519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-01-03T12:06:09.206764+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:15

2017-01-03T12:08:29.105329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fwc-node.herokuapp.com request_id=02b51d22-e888-40da-a24e-9ef9788ce3e5 fwd="2.102.204.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

If I have left anything important out I can add it. I just want to get to a point where my app is live so I can view it on Heroku. It all works locally, but I have to run mongod before running npm start. Also nodemon doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: mongo isn't running locally on heroku, you'll need to host the database somewhere

Comment: I tried using mLab, but I don't know how to reference it in my code, do I just replace 27017 with the link to the database on mLab?

Comment: LOTS of tutorials on this just a google search away. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

Comment: Thankyou! I wasn't 100% what to look for.